# NextGen Gallery Slideshow Positioning Issue

Tags: gallery, plugin-nextgen-gallery

I have been having an issue with the non-flash version of the NextGen Slideshow on my website.

The slideshow seems to initially load the first slide about 5px below the desired position. The slide then moves up about a second or 2 later into the correct position. I have tried putting the slideshow in other widget areas and all result in the same positioning error.

The page in question in here: [www.ukjiayuan.com](http://www.ukjiayuan.com)

So far have been unable to get any support, but would really appreciate it if anyone can reccomend a solution.

Many Thanks

Comment: Can you add two screenshots showing the right and the wrong position? I assume that this is related to the fact that the gallery is loaded and it takes some time until the gallery is fully loaded. For example when I visit your page with javascript switched off, there is a loading image only.

Comment: Have just solved the problem. Although thanks for reminding me... I should show an image instead of the loading symbol for those with javascript switched off i guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone has just answered the question for me on the wordpress forum.

It turns out that there was 5px of padding in the gallerys css file (line 301) that I hadn't found:

.ngg-widget, .ngg-widget-slideshow {
margin:0;
overflow:hidden;
padding:5px 0 0 0; <--- change this to 0 0 0 0 or just 0
text-align:left

I didn't add this, so it seems like the css have been like this in the first place. So if anyone else has this problem in the future just change that 5 to a 0.